# Как распараллелить скалярное произведение векторов?

Tags: c++, mpi, parallel

Помогите пожалуйста на основе кода реализовать параллельный алгоритм вычисления скалярного произведения в рамках функции double scalmult (int n, double* a, double* b). В качестве имени функции на каждом процессе должно возвращаться вычисленное значение скалярного произведения,воспользоваться функцией глобальной редукции, чтобы собрать полученные результаты.

Сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include "Exercise1_dll.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Функция выделения памяти под вектор
double* malloc_array(int n)
{
    double* a = new double[n];
    return a;
}

// Функция освобождения памяти 
int free_array(double*a, int n)
{
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}

double scalmult(int n, double* a, double* b)
{
    // Определения числа доступных процессов и размера подзадач
    int nn = 100;
    int n1 = nn / 4;

    double* a1 = malloc_array(n1);
    double* b1 = malloc_array(n1);

    MPI_Scatter(&a[0], n1, MPI_INT, &a1[0], n1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(&b[0], n1, MPI_INT, &b1[0], n1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Вычисление скалярного произведения
    double sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += a1[i] * b1[i];
    }
    double globalsum = sum;
    MPI_Reduce(&sum, &globalsum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    globalsum = sqrt(globalsum);

    free_array(a1, nn);
    free_array(b1, nn);

    return globalsum;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Иницилизация MPI
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // Определение размера задачи и подзадач
    int n = 100;
    int n1 = n / size;
    if (rank < n - n1 * size) n1++;

    // Выделение памяти 
    double *a = malloc_array(n1);
    double *b = malloc_array(n1);

    // Заполнение векторов
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        b[i] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    double sc = scalmult(n, a, b);
    double sc1;

    MPI_Gather(&sc, n1, MPI_INT, &sc1, n1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        cout << "The Program is RUN on " << size << " CPU" << endl;
        cout << "Result: " << sc1 << endl;
    }

    // Вызов функции из библиотеки, которая проводит проверку корректности реализации алгоритма и его ускорения
    // submit(scalmult);

    free_array(a, n);
    free_array(b, n);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляций выводят ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде у меня разные массивы, но у них адрес одинаковые. Можете сказать мои ошибки?

Comment: "В качестве имени функции на каждом процессе должно возвращаться вычисленное значение" - ??

Comment: "При компиляций выводят ошибку" - это ошибка выполнения,  а не компиляции.

Comment: @Igor задание такой. У меня в функций MPI_Scatter() две разные массивы. Но почему показывает один и тот же адрес?